# 8 Directional Pathfinding (A*) - Inconsistently Finding Path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

Newbie here so sorry if I don't describe the problem well.

I'm attempting to create an 8 directional pathfinding script. I've followed the majority of a tutorial but wanted to change it up to work in a way that's easier for me to understand.

The GetNeighbours method works in 4 directions but not diagonally. I'm using a Dictionary to index the x and y value in a node (cell). I know this is not efficient but it's easier for me to understand and more flexible.

Anyway, the pathing works only sometimes. Seems like I can't get the neighbouring cells whenever I need to move to the top or left row. If I put holes in the tilemap it also messes up the pathing but only when I go behind the holes sometimes, see image:
not working:

[image: 1]

working:

[image: 2]

Any help would be amazing!

```
    public List<Node> GetNeighbours(Node node)
    {
        List<Node> neighbours = new List<Node>();
        int checkX = node.gridX;
        int checkY = node.gridY;

        //left
        if (nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX-1, checkY))) 
        {
            neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX-1, checkY)]);
        }
        //right
        if (nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX +1, checkY)))
        {
            neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX + 1, checkY)]);
        }
        //up
        if (nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY + 1)))
        {
            neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY +1)]);
        }
        //down
        if (nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY - 1)))
        {
            neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY - 1)]);
        }

        //top left
        if (nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX - 1, checkY - 1)) && nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY + 1)) && nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX - 1, checkY - 1)));
        {
            neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX -1, checkY + 1)]);
        }
        //top right
        if(nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX + 1, checkY)) && nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY + 1)) && nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX + 1, checkY + 1)))
        {
            neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX + 1, checkY + 1)]);
        }
        //bottom left
        if(nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX-1, checkY)) && nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY -1 )) && nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX - 1, checkY - 1)))
        {
           neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX - 1, checkY - 1)]);
        }
        //bottomright
        if (nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX +1, checkY)) && nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY -1)) && nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX + 1, checkY - 1)))
        {
            neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX + 1, checkY - 1)]);
        }
        
        // Debug.Log("number of neighbours added is: " + neighbours.Count);
        return neighbours;
    }
```

The Pathfinding Class

```
public class Pathfiding
{
    public static List<Vector2Int> FindPath(Grid grid, Vector2Int startPos, Vector2Int endPos)
    {
        List<Node> nodes_path = _ImpFindPath(grid, startPos, endPos);

        if (!grid.nodes.ContainsKey(startPos) || !grid.nodes.ContainsKey(endPos))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            //get nodes and return a list of points
            List<Vector2Int> ret = new List<Vector2Int>();

            if (nodes_path != null)
            {
                foreach (Node n in nodes_path)
                {
                    ret.Add(new Vector2Int(n.gridX, n.gridY)); //load all nodes to check
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }//end FindPath////

    private static List<Node> _ImpFindPath(Grid grid, Vector2Int startPos, Vector2Int endPos)
    {
        Node startNode;
        Node targetNode;

      
            startNode = grid.nodes[startPos];
            targetNode = grid.nodes[endPos];
        

        List<Node> openSet = new List<Node>();
        HashSet<Node> closedSet = new HashSet<Node>();

        openSet.Add(startNode);


        while (openSet.Count > 0)
        {
            Node currentNode = openSet[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < openSet.Count; i++)
            {
                //only check nodes with better f costs
                if (openSet[i].fCost < currentNode.fCost || openSet[i].fCost == currentNode.fCost && openSet[i].hCost < currentNode.hCost)
                {
                    currentNode = openSet[i];
                }
            }

            openSet.Remove(currentNode);
            closedSet.Add(currentNode);

            if (currentNode == targetNode)
            {
                return RetracePath(grid, startNode, targetNode);
            }

            foreach (Node neighbour in grid.GetNeighbours(currentNode))
            {
                if (neighbour.walkPenalty <= 0 || closedSet.Contains(neighbour))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                int newMovementCostToNeighbour = currentNode.gCost + GetDistance(currentNode, neighbour) * (int)(10.0f * neighbour.walkPenalty);

                if (newMovementCostToNeighbour < neighbour.gCost || !openSet.Contains(neighbour))
                {
                    neighbour.gCost = newMovementCostToNeighbour;
                    neighbour.hCost = GetDistance(neighbour, targetNode);
                    neighbour.parent = currentNode;

                    if (!openSet.Contains(neighbour))
                        openSet.Add(neighbour);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm wondering what are these three conditions in the diagonal movement?

Comment: I was using that to check the up, down, left, right nodes and if either of each pair (top and left) don't add the diagonal node. I couldn't figure out a cleaner way to make it so the pathing doesn't cut corners.

Comment: What do you mean by "cutting corners"? So do you need the diagonal movement at all?

Comment: I mean if there was a wall in the left (x-1) then if the character moved to the top left (x-1,y+1) it would move over the corner of the wall. I do want the character/enemies to be able to move diagonally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three errors in the `//top left` condition:

1. There should be no semicolon at the end of the `if` statement. It makes the `if` statement useless and even worse it always executes the block below. So a diagonal path option towards top-left is always present.
2. Once you fix the first error, you need to change `checkY - 1` to `checkY` in the first predicate of the `if` condition.
3. And you need to change `checkY - 1` to `checkY + 1` in the last predicate.

```cs
//top left
if (nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX - 1, checkY)) &&
    nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY + 1)) &&
    nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX - 1, checkY + 1)))
{
  neighbours.Add(nodes[new Vector2Int(checkX -1, checkY + 1)]);
}
```

It would be even better to use `TryGetValue` to avoid one more `struct` construction and lookup:

```cs
//top left
if (nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX - 1, checkY)) &&
    nodes.ContainsKey(new Vector2Int(checkX, checkY + 1)) &&
    nodes.TryGetValue(new Vector2Int(checkX - 1, checkY + 1), out var n))
{
  neighbours.Add(n);
}
```

I am not sure if these are all the direct errors in your code, just try it.

There is one more indirect error related to the diagonal movement. I do not understand why you need to check the 4-neighborhood path along with the diagonal check. If the 4-neighbors must be present anyhow, why do you explicitly add the diagonal movement? Or is it another error, that for diagonal movement the non-diagonal predicates should be actually omitted?

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot, that semicolon was a big issue. Thank you! I'll change it to trygetvalue, didn't know I could do that! The trygetvalue have fixed the 'keynotfoundexception' error that keeps getting thrown. The other issue was the checkX and checkY's. Fixed the directions and now it works! Thanks again.